# How to create dictionary from attributes of objects?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I have a dictionary called log_entries:

```
log_entries = {datetime.date(2015, 5, 2): {'before_bedtime': '',
  'before_breakfast': '',
  'before_dinner': '',
  'before_lunch': ''},
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 3): {'before_bedtime': '',
  'before_breakfast': '',
  'before_dinner': '',
  'before_lunch': ''},
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 4): {'before_bedtime': '',
  'before_breakfast': '',
  'before_dinner': '',
  'before_lunch': ''},
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 5): {'before_bedtime': '',
  'before_breakfast': '',
  'before_dinner': '',
  'before_lunch': ''},
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 6): {'before_bedtime': '',
  'before_breakfast': '',
  'before_dinner': '',
  'before_lunch': ''},
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 7): {'before_bedtime': '',
  'before_breakfast': '',
  'before_dinner': '',
  'before_lunch': ''},
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 8): {'before_bedtime': '',
  'before_breakfast': '',
  'before_dinner': '',
  'before_lunch': ''}}
```

I have an iterable of objects called bg_readings, and each reading has a datetime attribute, a meal attribute (strings... either 'before_breakfast', 'before_lunch', 'before_dinner', or 'before_bedtime'), and a reading attribute (an int).

For a given date in log_entries, I want to populate the nested dictionary's `before_<meal>` values with the bg_reading's reading value for the bg_reading with the same date.

I've tried the code below, **but the result is a log_entries dictionary where each value is from the last bg_reading in the bg_readings iterable.**

```
for key in log_entries:
    for reading in bg_readings:
        if reading.logDatetime.date() == key:
            log_entries[key][reading.meal] = reading.reading
```

And the result of the above code (**The data for each date key in the dictionary is only from the last object in the bg_readings iterable, and not from the bg_reading with matching date**):

```
{datetime.date(2015, 5, 2): {'before_bedtime': 119,
  'before_breakfast': 99,
  'before_dinner': 115,
  'before_lunch': 111},
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 3): {'before_bedtime': 119,
  'before_breakfast': 99,
  'before_dinner': 115,
  'before_lunch': 111},
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 4): {'before_bedtime': 119,
  'before_breakfast': 99,
  'before_dinner': 115,
  'before_lunch': 111},
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 5): {'before_bedtime': 119,
  'before_breakfast': 99,
  'before_dinner': 115,
  'before_lunch': 111},
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 6): {'before_bedtime': 119,
  'before_breakfast': 99,
  'before_dinner': 115,
  'before_lunch': 111},
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 7): {'before_bedtime': 119,
  'before_breakfast': 99,
  'before_dinner': 115,
  'before_lunch': 111},
 datetime.date(2015, 5, 8): {'before_bedtime': 119,
  'before_breakfast': 99,
  'before_dinner': 115,
  'before_lunch': 111}}
```

How can I properly populate this dictionary with the corresponding bg_reading values?

I ultimately want to pass the resulting dictionary to a Django template and present a table of bg_readings by date and meal, so I'd be happy with a solution that either uses views logic, template tags, or both.

Comment: if this is a key reading.logDatetime.date() a small improvement would be: for reading in bg_readings: log_entries[reading.logDatetime.date()]=... and you don't need to do two iterations.

Comment: How could the readings be an iterable of integers but also contain a date? I presume you mean a dictionary of readings mapping dates to readings.

Comment: the keys in the dictionary are datetime objects, what is exactly returned by reading.logDatetime.date()?

Comment: `date()` on any `datetime` object returns a `date` object containing just the date. It's what I'd use to look up the corresponding sub-dictionary, as @Ale recommended.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi bg_readings is an iterable of objects, not ints

Comment: @Ale: Thanks for the suggestion, but that raises a KeyError for bg_readings with dates that are not in the log_entries dictionary.

Comment: @mcastle use .get() method of the dictionary or catch the exception and continue